# IOS UIWebView , divide into multiple UIWebViews ?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView`  that loads a long page , lets say 4 times it's height.

Is there a way that I can divide each 25% of the long page into 4 `UIWebViews`?

Can I scroll the `UIWebView` content of the long page, and sad the 4 out coming result each in a `UIWebView` ???

I'm using the code below to scroll and its working, but I can't save the scrolled content and when i use the `UIWebView` into two different locations it is removed from the first

```
  NSString* goToOffsetFunc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" function pageScroll(xOffset){ window.scroll(xOffset,0); } "];
  NSString* goTo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pageScroll(%f)", pageOffset];


    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:goToOffsetFunc];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:goTo];
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html), although you'll still need a way to break your content into pages.

Comment: I'm using UIPageViewController , and its working very gr8 , but in arabic content (inside epub ) its talking too much time to load . 
so i thought of running the loading action in background as in ibooks , but it still hangs the movement of UIPageViewController .